# ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgadmin-4

for load the script in my work throw me this error , i counted manually and give the line 1162 , the end of the line count 21787 , and i check that line and i'm not seeing the error
Someone know what can be the trouble?

also the postgres version in the dabase is 9.6 and i install the 11 i don't know if that can be a trouble

```
LINE 1012: \N 4 a446c64465c254aca3bf7ae99ef6ee9c MD5 156360018883456211...
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 21779


1011: COPY public.bitstream (bitstream_id, bitstream_format_id, checksum, checksum_algorithm, internal_id, deleted, store_number, sequence_id, size_bytes, uuid) FROM stdin;

1012:\N 4   a446c64465c254aca3bf7ae99ef6ee9c    MD5 156360018883456211287081168307980169094 t   0   1   15165   1ab67171-6431-4667-b764-9383727a0c18 

1013: \N    2   8a4605be74aa9ea9d79846c1fba20a33    MD5 90906716375288007825784141138015773604  t   0   2   1748    4b3701e4-e901-4f5f-88b2-4baf7910021b

1162: \N    4   57f901993fd3312441863f6ff4352677    MD5 137020448368323621812281407028089347246 f   0   1   474545  eab040f7-1702-4f89-a44a-f2d466bf655e
```

Comment: Define 'load script'? It looks to me like it is coming from Postgres `pg_dump` file, is that correct? If so how did you dump it, command used and the Postgres version used? Also explain further what you mean about versions 9.6 and 11? Add the answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

That is a follow-up error.

One likely cause for that is if you try to restore a dump generated with `pg_dump -F p` with a client other than `psql`.

Such a dump mixes SQL and data:

```
COPY mytable (x, y) FROM STDIN;
1   one
2   two
\.
```

Clients like pgAdmin will gag on that.